# Google map is not fully loaded on my android phone but my current location button and zoom in/zoom out button are showing

Tags: android, google-maps

Android map is not fully loaded on my cell phone but my current location button and zoom in/zoom out button are showing.

Answer (score 0):

If the maps rendering as grey in color, u can use

google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Answer (score -1):

Are you by chance running this on a Lollipop device? Try a non lollipop device if you are... IDK why but I cannot get the Map to load and tile data in a lollipop device but all other devices run it just fine.

Comment: I am using also android studio emulater android 6 but i have same issue.